# How to set the maximum number of iterations in a loop?

Tags: python-3.x, loops

I'm accessing to a link in which I would like to set the number of retries to 3. This means I will exit the loop after 3 retries. Could you please elaborate on how to achieve my goal?

```
import requests, time
session = requests.Session()
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0'}

r = session.get('https://www.larousse.fr/conjugaison/anglais/abnegate/11338', headers = headers)
while r.status_code != 200:
    time.sleep(2)
    r = session.get(link, headers = headers)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep a counter and a loop that enables you to iterate as many times:

```
while r.status_code != 200 and count < 3:
```

Like:

```
import requests, time
session = requests.Session()
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0'}

count = 1
r = session.get('https://www.larousse.fr/conjugaison/anglais/abnegate/11338', headers = headers)
while r.status_code != 200 and count < 3:
    time.sleep(2)
    r = session.get(link, headers = headers) 
    count += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a counter.
while `condition 1` and `counter < limit`

Answer (score 1):

You could just add a second variable that counts the number of attempts:

```
import requests, time
session = requests.Session()
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0'}

r = session.get('https://www.larousse.fr/conjugaison/anglais/abnegate/11338', headers = headers)
tries = 0
while r.status_code != 200 and tries != 3:
    time.sleep(2)
    r = session.get(link, headers = headers)
    tries += 1
```

Comment: I think this will execute four times (I'm assuming the one outside the loop also included).